# Voice recording applet/flash in a webbrowser

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-3, applet, voice-recording

I'm going to do a voice recording plugin/addon on a website that will record audio and send it to the server for further processing. I have had two suggestions; either write a java applet or use flash. The service is supposed to work for all major browsers(IE, Firefox, chrome,..).

I'm new to this area of development and is looking for tips on how to proceed with this. What is the pro's and con's for each solution?

For java applet, what Java speech API library do you recommend? I want a simple, small library, I only need voice input.

Also, I am puzzled by Flash development, I can't find any good information about development, the adobe website dosn't make much sense. What is the programming language for flash, and how do you actually run it in html code? I have found ActionScript 3, is that used to create Flash plugins and can it perform voice recording?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn flash:

http://gotoandlearn.com/index.php

How flash runs is, the swf files are passed to the flash plugin after the flash plugin as been invoked by the browser via certain tags, usually javascript. The flash objects are loaded seamlessly into the browser to conform to layout parameters and then the flash binaries (swfs) are executed in the actionscript virtual machine, with the output being rendered to the browser.

If you want to capture user sound input and save it, you can do this easily in flash. Here's a minimal library to accomplish just this:

http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1858

Comment: Also to further answer your questions about how flash works you're not really writing "plugins" for flash, you're just writing scripts for existing API's inside the flash player. These scripts are compiled into a binary SWF format, represented as something called actionscript byte code, or ABC. The rest is explained in my answer. The ABC is executed over the flash virtual machine, where the bytecode is processed using a JIT compiler (nanoJIT) to output proper instructions based on the platform. Flash is based on the open source project Tamarin. http://www.mozilla.org/projects/tamarin/

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript 3 is used to create Flash Applications and in the lastest versions can be used to perform voice recording. I think it is definatly the way to ago as flash is way more distributed and known to users then java.